# The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object '<null>') is missing

Tags: unity-game-engine

`The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object '<null>') is missing!`

How to find this missing script?

However I have checked every single gameobject in my scene and none of them have a missing script

Comment: This can happen when you make changes to code while the game is running in the editor.   After stopping playback everything should be as it was prior to pressing play.

Comment: can we get a bit more details? Is this on runtime or an issue in the editor itself?

Comment: no other errors. it keeps occurring.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases clicking the error in the console will highlight gameobject with the issue.

Also, it can be not only scene gameobject, but also any prefab that your scene refers to.

Comment: since when does the console do that?

Comment: at least for many years. I don't know about "originally"

Comment: my console does not do that... which version and platform are u using